# Splitting words into variables

Tags: python

I have been doing some Python coding recntly and wanted to do the following:

```
import shlex
shlex.split("this is a test")
print (shlex.split("this is a test"))
```

It works, but I want to store the split phrase into different variables, if anyone can help me that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to store them in variables? What are you going to do with them?

Comment: It's a bit of a complex project, but to make the code understand them, it will like, store each word and define them. So I just want to store them as strings.

Comment: Why not keeping it into a list? That would make it easy for iterating.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
>>> str = "this is a test"
>>> arr = str.split(" ")
>>> arr
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
>>> arr[0]
'this'
>>> a = arr[0]
>>> b = arr[1]
>>> c = arr[2]
>>> d = arr[3]
>>> a
'this'
```

Comment: Or `a, b, c, d = arr`

Answer (score 0):

`split()` returns a list. Since you probably don't know how many words there will be, you can't declare all the individual variables you will need. Instead, you should use the returned list and use it as appropriate:

```
words = shlex.split("this is a test");
```

Note that this stores the list of words in a **single** variable, rather than trying to store each word in its own variable. I suggest you study more about how to manipulate lists in Python.